# Commutator estimates for $-(-\Delta)^s$, with $s \in (1,2)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I'm currently trying to work with the non-local operator given by 
$$
  (-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}f(x)= c_s\text{P.V} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{-f(x+y)-f(x-y)+2f(x)}{|y|^{1+s}} dy,
$$
where $f :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a smooth function and $c_s$ is a constant. I am focusing on the case $s \in (1,2)$.

I am particularly interested on some sort the approximations (a remainder estimate for an approximate Leibnitz rule) for $(-\Delta)^s (f^n)(x)$ where $f$ is a $C^{1,s^\prime}_\text{loc}(\mathbb R)$, with $s^\prime >s $ that decays faster than any polynomial and $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer.This article seems to suggest that we could take
$$
(-\Delta)^\frac{s}{2} (f^n)(x) \approx (-\Delta)^\frac{s}{2} (f)(x)f^{n-1}(x) + s(n-1)(-\Delta)^\frac{s-1}{2}(f)(x) f^\prime(x) f^{n-2}(x).
$$
Is it possible to quantify the error? I was hoping for a $L^p$ type of estimate.

I read some of [professor's Tao lecture notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247b.1.07w/notes6.pdf) in harmonic analysis, in which he points out that one does not expect in general a good Chain rule estimate for $(-\Delta)^{s}F(f)$ if $s \in (1,2)$ for general $F$, however, he says one can expect such given enough regularity for $F$. I know that the commutator estimate seems like a step further, but I was hoping this would be possible for the polynomial case.

Any bibliography is well appreciated, I am just starting to navigate on the subject and analysis is not my first area.

Comment: You should look for Kato-Ponce commutator estimates and Kenig-Ponce-Vega commutator estimates. For a view of the subject check Li's paper <a href="https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=0213-2230&vol=35&iss=1&rank=2">here</>

Comment: That was exactly the kind of result I was looking for, thank you very much!